# Hahn-Banach Theorem for finite dimensional vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples

I am studying the Hahn-Banach Theorem but I'm having a hard time following some of the examples presented in my notes, so I would like to first study some small examples which help me to get some insight into the theorem.

I wonder if you know of any example(s) involving finite vector spaces where the Hahn-Banach Theorem is used?

I am asking for examples with finite vector spaces since in this case linear transformations have matrix representations and I think then it'll be easier to work with.

Comment: Maybe you can write precisely what the statement is you want to understand. Wikipedia suggests that Hahn-Banach is about extending certain linear transformations on a subspace of a Banach space to the whole space. If that is the case, then this is understandable in the finite-dimensional setting as simply the observation that if $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space and $U \subset V$ is a subspace then any basis for $U$ can be extended to a basis for $V$. Thus any linear transformation $U \rightarrow W$ can be extended to $V$ by forcing an extension to be trivial on the extra basis vectors.

Comment: Also, the key problem that Hahn-Banach addresses is extending the linear functional while preserving continuity (merely extending a linear functional is no problem even in infinite dimensions).